How to include() with two relations?
How do i use include() with two relations?
CustomerSupplier has CustomerId and CustomerAddressId the relation matches the field in the table CustomerAddress.
public partial class CustomerSupplier
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("CustomerID")]
    [Required]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Column("CustomerAddressID")]
    public int? CustomerAddressId { get; set; }
    public CustomerAddress CustomerAddress { get; set; }

    [Column("CustomerContactID")]
    public int? CustomerContactId { get; set; }

    [Column("SupplierID")]
    [Required]
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    [Column("SupplierContactID")]
    public int? SupplierContactId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
    public string ContractNo { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}

public partial class CustomerAddress
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("CustomerID")]
    [Required]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Column("CustomerAddressID")]
    [Required]
    public int CustomerAddressId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string MatchCode { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool? Inactive { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
}

Im looking for something link this:
public async Task<IQueryable<BobbyTest.Models.ControlCenter.CustomerSupplier>> 
    GetCustomerSuppliers(Query query = null)
{
    var items = Context.CustomerSuppliers.AsQueryable();
    items = items.Include(i => i.Customer);
    items = items.Include(i => i.Supplier);
    items = items.Include(i => i.CustomerAddress); //<- Check the CustomerAddressID from CustomerAddress in addition to the CustomerID
    OnCustomerSuppliersRead(ref items);
    return await Task.FromResult(items);
}

The SQL-Query would look like this:
select cs.CustomerID, cs.SupplierID, ca.MatchCode 
from CustomerSupplier cs 
inner join CustomerAddress ca 
    on cs.CustomerID = ca.customerID and cs.CustomerAddressID = ca.CustomerAddressID;


I do not see relations. Could you please post real classes instead of text?

You really should show the classes and mapping code (if present). Also, please indicate the exact EF version. If this is EF-core, change to [entity-framework-core] tag + a versioned tag.

You are right, it`s much clearer this way.

Remove SQL and post classes.

And add the configuration of the relationship CustomerSupplier.CustomerAddress (i.e. as asked before: the mapping code). If configured correctly, you only have to Include the navigation property and there's no need to worry about checking Ids. That's the vague part in this question: it's not clear why you worry about these Ids in the first place.

You need to include the entire object class, not the properties! like:
var CustomerSupplier = db.CustomerSupplier
          .Include(x => x.CustomerAddress);

This will return all the properties from CustomerAddress linked with CustomerSupplier!

sry, missunderstanding.
I need a query to handel the two relations to the CustomerAddress.
The return from CustomerSupplier should looks like:
CustomerID, SupplierID, CustomerAddress.Location.
10000           70000        Berlin
10001           70003        New York

What is misunderstanding ? The answer ? If soo, you could check more details about EF Core relationship here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

When you do the select like i told you before, you will get all the information you need! If you want omit the other properties you just need to add .Select(x => new { [... properties you want...]} after the .Include method.

My question.
Thx for the link. In this link the relation are only treated with one relation. In my case i have to relations to the Table CustomerAddress(CustomerID and CustomerAddressID). The include works fine so far with the default Syntax (x => x.CustomerAddress) but with this syntax i get all CustomerAddress-Locations for the Customer. Where i only need the specific one.

You could improve your select with a where clause ? .Include(CustomerAddress).Where(x => x.CustomerAddressID == id)

You could check this link to learn more about linq queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/try-samples/101-linq-samples/

you need to add the where clause after the include, example:
var CustomerSupplier = db.CustomerSupplier
      .Include(x => x.CustomerAddress)
      .where(x => x.CustomerAddressID == id);

Without putting the where, the query will not have good performance since it will go through the entire "CustomerAddress" table

var CustomerSupplier = db.CustomerSupplier
.Include(x => x.CustomerAddress.where(s => s.CustomerAddressId == x.CustomerAddressId ));
It might help you. Good luck
